# Uri Based on Real story?

Tags: realism, uri-the-surgical-strike

As per the movie prologue, [Uri: The surgical strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uri:_The_Surgical_Strike) is based on a real story,
but how many incidents of the movie are real and do they have the real connection?

Let's say certain events of the movie like

- Major Karan Singh martyred during [Uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Uri_attack) attack, But in the [list of martyrs](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-news-india/uri-terror-attack-list-of-jawans-who-died-fighting-terrorists/) I see no major, most of them are sepoys, naik, Lance Naik & havildars.
- Major Karan Singh daughter sobbing during the funeral (looks a lot like [Col. MN Rai](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4rnfQwbess)'s funeral, who was martyred in Palwal J&K but he is from [Gorkha Reg.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorkha_regiments_(India)) And not from [Dogra Reg.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogra_Regiment))
- Wife of Karan Singh's emotions are way similar to [Major Akshay Girish](https://indianexpress.com/article/trending/trending-in-india/major-akshay-girish-wife-sangeetha-being-you-facebook-page-post-heart-touching-going-viral-4961377/)'s wife & he was from 51 Engineer Regiment of the Bengal Sappers.
- It was Nagrota where the terrorists were disguised as Police cops and not military officers.
- Introduction of Major Vihaan Singh Shergill and his [past missions](https://www.hindustantimes.com/india/after-chandel-ambush-dogra-soldiers-stay-on-in-manipur-to-hit-back/story-6c9fiMIEkkDZHU0afDgrhK.html).
- DRDO and ISRO's involvement.

I am trying to understand how much of the film is actual and how many of the real incidents are bolted together to form a conventional story.

I have referred to the [list of Terror attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terrorist_incidents_in_India)

Comment: It's more of a mixture of all the **true events** happened over course of last few years and it's retaliation in form of surgical strike.

Answer (score 4):

This has been addressed by the main lead Vicky Kaushal himself in an interview with [Jaby Koay](https://www.youtube.com/user/jabykoay):

> There was some based on defense protocols and intelligence protocols you cant share some information in the public domain. So those liberties were taken for example the identities of the actual armed officer were gone for surgical strikes you cannot reveal their identities. You just cannot reveal in public domain. **So the identities were changed the names were changed, their family, the history, the backstory was changed** because you just can't reveal that some moment in the planning of the surgical strike like for instance yes there was special drone that was designed for this mission there was raw agent in Pakistan, they were giving information so all of that was going on but the detail to the tee you cannot give because that's intelligence.

Full video of the said interview:

Answer (score 0):

The main Hero of URI is Major Vihaan Singh Shergill of the Indian Army worked as a leader in a covert operation against a group of militants who attacked a base in [Uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Uri_attack), Kashmir, in 2016 and killed many soldiers.
Vicky Kaushal is considered as the best suitable actor for this role in the movie URI. Vicky Kaushal menacingly calm as a military mind - inspiring his peers, with an infectious energy that is impossible to resist.

Inspiring from the story people started to take inspiration to join Indian Defence Like [Airforce](https://theyuvas.com/airforce-group-x-y/), Navy and Army.